# Pairs of initial and final elements in a column of datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, datetime

I have a time column like this:

| Time |
| --- |
| 7:00:00 |
| 7:15:00 |
| 7:30:00 |
| 8:00:00 |
| 8:15:00 |
| 8:30:00 |
| 8:45:00 |

and I need to get the first and last element of each subset of times that are continuous and change only every 15 minutes. I.e., the first subset would be: `{"start_time": 7:00:00, "end_time":7:30:00}` and the second subset would be: `{"start_time":8:00:00, "end_time":8:45:00}`, so I need to return a list with those two dictionaries like:

```
[{"start_time": 7:00:00, "end_time":7:30:00}, {"start_time":8:00:00, "end_time":8:45:00}]
```

another example:

| Time |
| --- |
| 7:00:00 |
| 7:15:00 |
| 7:30:00 |

Returns: `[{"start_time": 7:00:00, "end_time":7:30:00}]`

The last one:

| Time |
| --- |
| 7:00:00 |
| 7:15:00 |
| 7:30:00 |
| 8:00:00 |
| 9:00:00 |
| 10:00:00 |
| 10:15:00 |
| 10:30:00 |
| 11:00:00 |

returns:     `[{"start_time": 7:00:00, "end_time":7:30:00}, {"start_time":10:00:00, "end_time":10:30:00}]`

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without looping one row at a time.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I was trying to create another column shifted 1 down, and do the subtraction to see which rows have a difference of 15 min between them, but I don't know how to proceed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covvert the column to timedelta then calculate the diff between previous and current row to get the number of seconds now compare it with 5 minuts to flag the change. Then group the dataframe by continuous blocks (i.e mask.cumsum()) and aggregate Time with first and last

```
mask = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).diff().dt.total_seconds() != 900
df.groupby(mask.cumsum())['Time'].agg(['first', 'last']).to_dict(orient='records')
```

---

```
[{'first': '7:00:00', 'last': '7:30:00'},
 {'first': '8:00:00', 'last': '8:45:00'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
import pandas as pd

times = [
"7:00:00",
"7:15:00",
"7:30:00",
"8:00:00",
"9:00:00",
"10:00:00",
"10:15:00",
"10:30:00",
"11:00:00"]
times = [pd.Timedelta(t) for t in times]

df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=['Times'])

fifteen = pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
prev = None
for t in df['Times']:
    if prev:
        if t - prev == fifteen:
            prev = t
            continue
        if curr != prev:
            print({'start':curr, 'end':prev})
    curr = prev = t
```

Output:

```
{'start': Timedelta('0 days 07:00:00'), 'end': Timedelta('0 days 07:30:00')}
{'start': Timedelta('0 days 10:00:00'), 'end': Timedelta('0 days 10:30:00')}
```